# UTF-8 vs UTF-16 and UTF-32 conversion confusion

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, utf-8, computer-science

I'm kinda confused about conversion of unicode characters into hexadecimal values.

I'm using this website to get hexadecimal value for characters.  (https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter)

If I put "A" and convert then I get something like:

```
0041 --> UTF-16
00000041 --> UTF-32
41 --> UTF-8
00065 --> Decimal Value
```

This above output makes sense because we can convert all these hexadecimal values into 65.

Now, If i put "Я" (without quotes) and convert it then I get values like.

```
042f --> UTF-16
0000042f --> UTF-32
d0af --> UTF-8
01071 --> Decimal Value
```

This output doesn't make sense to me because not all these hexadecimal values convert back to 1071.

If you you take **d0af** and try to convert it back to decimal value then you will get **53423**.

This is something that is really confusing for me and I've searching online to find answers about this conversion but so far I've not been able to find any good answer.

So, I'm wondering if anyone here can help.  (that would mean alot)  // Thanks in advance.

*you can also see below link for example of this conversion in binary.* (and can you explain why utf-8 binary value is different in last example??)

[http://kunststube.net/encoding/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4JYD.png)

Comment: You're reading too much into how character encodings work. They each have their own standard. You should compare standards rather than draw conclusions from sample outputs. For example, the standand on UTF-16 would tell you that it, too, is a variable length encoding, .

Comment: Hi @TomBlodget you're right they both are variable length encoding UTF-8 and UTF-16. The thing is I'm learning more about them because I'm a computer science student and I love learning about the behind the scene working of the stuff.

Comment: Great, just be careful out there. For example, the site you linked says "\x61 \xe4\xb8\xad \xd0\xaf" is UTF-8. It's not a standard notation for discourse on Unicode text and it means different things in different languages. It would be fine as a C or C++ string literal with the compiler's execution character set as UTF-8. It would be okay as a Python byte string but not as a character string. It would mean different characters in JavaScript. In many languages, it would be invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-8 uses variable length encoding (can use 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes to store a single character).

[image]

In this case:

```
d0af = 11010000 10101111
```

`110` at the start tells us to expect 2 bytes when decoding it (looking at the byte 1 column of the schematic). When decoding we use the binary digits that follow the first 0 in the byte. So,
`110x xxxx` the x's are our first lot of values for our actual unicode value. Every additional byte follows the pattern of `10xx xxxx`. So taking the values from byte 1 & 2 we get:

```
110[10000] 10[101111] = 
      V        V
     10000 101111 = 42f = 1071
```

The reason this is done is that for common characters less bytes are needed for transmission and storage. But on the odd occasion that a uncommon character is needed it can still be used at part of UTF-8.

If you have any questions, please comment.

Comment: Thank you so much, before reading your answer I also read a blog post which cleared it for me but your answer further clears some stuff. BIG THANK YOU 